# Is there a point in 6-dimensional space satisfying these polynomial inequalities?

Tags: polynomials, inequalities, nonlinear-optimization, computer-algebra

I would like to know if there is a point $(a, b, p, q, x, y) \in [0,1]^6$ satisfying the following collection of inequalities.

$b \ge a$

$q \ge p$

$y \ge x$

$a \ge p \ge a^2$

$b \ge q \ge b^2$

$p \ge x \ge a p$

$q \ge y \ge bq$

$x \ge 2p - a$

$y \ge 2q - b$

$a^3 -3ap + 2x \ge 0$

$b^3- 3 b q +2 y \ge 0$

$(a/2+b/2)^3-3 (a/2+b/2) (p/2+q/2)+x+y < 0$

This seems like the sort of question that should be possible to answer, if not by hand, then with some help from a computer. Unfortunately, I am not an expert, so my attempts to work this out with Mathematica have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you do in Mathematica?

Comment: I tried calling the FindInstance function with these constraints, but it doesn't return anything in a few hours. I might try a simple discretisation approach and see if an exhaustive search over the resulting 6-D grid can find such a point. Of course, I would think that this is not the most efficient way to approach something like this!

Comment: This is indeed too difficult (especially with too many variables) to have a reasonable chance of success with FindInstance. Meanwhile it should be easy to sample from the space that satisfies the first seven lines of inequalities, which would make the search more reasonable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the conditions hold for
$$(a, b, p, q, x, y)=\left(\frac{211}{500},\frac{531}{1000},\frac{96106069}{341750000},\frac{281961}{1000000},\frac{23996819}{170875000},\frac{149721291}{1000000000}\right).$$

---

This result was obtained by solving the system of all the (linear) inequalities containing $x$ but not $y$ and thus getting $p\ge x\ge \max(a p,2p-a,(3a p-a^3)/2)$ (which implies $p\le a$). Then piecewise expand $\max(a p,2p-a,(3a p-a^3)/2)$; note the three corresponding cases -- call them the $x$-cases. Similarly do with the roles of $x$ and $y$ interchanged, to get the three corresponding $y$-cases. In each of the 9 combinations of the $x$- and $y$-cases, minimize the left-hand side of the last inequality in $x,y$, then in $p,q$, and finally in $a,b$. Actually, it is the combination of the $x$-case when $\max(a p,2p-a,(3a p-a^3)/2)=(3a p-a^3)/2$ and the similar $y$-case that gives the above result.

---

Below is the image of a piece of a Mathematica notebook providing a verification of the above statement (click on the image to enlarge it):

[image]

Comment: Would you be so kind as to reveal to the rest of us how you found these numbers?

Comment: @AndrejBauer : I have now done this.

Comment: Thanks so much, this should be very helpful when I need to check such things in the future!

Comment: @BPN - Would you be so kind as to reveal to the rest of us where this problem comes from? Unless I’ve misunderstood, it’s remarkable that the prime 5 does not appear in the question but 1000000000 appears as a denominator in the answer.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft : the powers of $10$ arose just because of rounding certain irrational algebraic numbers, which latter were minimizing values of $a,b$ in the described above minimization.